# Where in Solana's codebase are new Geyser transactions notified?

Tags: transactions, geyser

I'm trying to understand the part of Solana's codebase where new transactions for Geyser are notified.

I've observed functions in GeyserService like `transaction_update_receiver` that seem to handle the updates. However, I'm having difficulty identifying where in the codebase the notification is triggered.

Can someone provide guidance or point me to the relevant section?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky to follow, but it all starts with the `transaction_notifier` which is part of the Geyser plugin service. You can follow how it gets pulled out at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/30055b02b5f9192be8851f03522b5f388933d659/core/src/validator.rs#L633 and eventually added to the `TransactionStatusService`.

`TransactionStatusService` spawns a thread which constantly receives new transactions from a receiver: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/30055b02b5f9192be8851f03522b5f388933d659/rpc/src/transaction_status_service.rs#L37

And finally, the sender side goes to many different parts of the validator: the TVU (to send notifications during replay), TPU (to send notifications when it's leader), and `ProcessBlockstore` (which mainly affects startup). You can trace `transaction_status_sender` through different parts of the first file (`core/src/validator.rs`) to see where it gets added, and then see where it gets used in `core/src/tvu.rs` and `core/src/tpu.rs`.